# Get confidence limits from Gaussian Process model in Python GPy

Tags: python, gaussian, confidence-interval, gpy

I calcualted a Gaussian Process model in Python using GPy:

```
ker0 = GPy.kern.Bias(input_dim=1,variance=1e-2)
...
m = GPy.models.GPRegression(x, y, ker0+ker2)
```

I can plot it with

```
m.plot()
plt.show
```

and it visualizes the points, the spline and the confidence limits. Now I want to extract the parameters and the confidence limits to use the data in another plot. My question is, how can I access these data.

if I print m I get

```
Name : GP regression
Objective : 31.9566881665
Number of Parameters : 4
Number of Optimization Parameters : 4
Updates : True
Parameters:
  GP_regression.           |              value  |  constraints  |  priors
  sum.bias.variance        |  7.48802926977e-61  |      +ve      |
  sum.spline.variance      |     -2.99999065833  |   -3.0,-1.0   |
  sum.spline.c             |      19.8308670902  |   0.0,300.0   |
  Gaussian_noise.variance  |      50.2314402955  |      +ve      |
```

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
m.sum.bias.variance
```

notice the `m.` at the beginning.

Comment: This answer is no longer up to date, as GPy now returns an error stating `'GPRegression' object has no attribute 'sum'`.

Comment: @Coolio2654 agreed. I have searched through `m.__dict__` and the best replacement I can find is `m._param_array_`, which gives an array of parameters (it seems to be the same order as it appears if you use `print(m)`)