# Python stats module: How to extract confidence/prediction intervals from GPy?

Tags: python, statistics, confidence-interval, gpy

After having looked through all the docs and examples online, I have not been able to find a way to extract information regarding the confidence or prediction intervals from [GPy](https://gpy.readthedocs.io/en/deploy/) models.

I generate dummy data like this,

```
## Generating data for regression
# First, regular sine wave + normal noise
x = np.linspace(0,40, num=300)
noise1 = np.random.normal(0,0.3,300)
y = np.sin(x) + noise1

## Second, an upward trending starting midway, with its own noise as well
temp = x[150:]
noise2 = 0.004*temp**2 + np.random.normal(0,0.1,150)
y[150:] = y[150:] + noise2

plt.plot(x, y)
```

and then estimate a basic model,

```
## Pre-processing
X = np.expand_dims(x, axis=1)
Y = np.expand_dims(y, axis=1)

## Model
kernel = GPy.kern.RBF(input_dim=1, variance=1., lengthscale=1.)
model1 = GPy.models.GPRegression(X, Y, kernel)
```

However, nothing makes it clear how to proceed from there...  Another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504866/get-confidence-limits-from-gaussian-process-model-in-python-gpy) tried asking the same thing, but that answer does not work any more, and seems rather unsatisfactory, for such an important element of statistical modelling.

Answer (score 2):

Given a model, and a set of target x values we want to generate the intervals at, you can extract the intervals using:

```
intervals = model.predict_quantiles( X = target_x_vals, quantiles = (2.5, 97.5) )
```

You can change the quantiles argument to get the appropriate width ones. The documentation for this function is found at: https://gpy.readthedocs.io/en/deploy/_modules/GPy/core/gp.html